# reloadData not working - suspect cell's reuseIdentifier

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a view controller that gets presented modally and changes some data that effects the data in a uitableview in the modal's parent view controller (a table view).

I call the tableview's reloadData method when the parent view reappears. I have confirmed that this code gets hit with a break point. My trouble is, reloadData isn't working. Here's the kicker - if I don't use reuseIdentifiers in the - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, the data reloads correctly. It looks like the reuseIdentifier is to blame.

I really want to continue to use the reuseIdentifier for my cells - how do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is unlikely to do with the reuse identifier. Please post your code for your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured, and you're right, it's not the reuseIdentifer.

I was nesting the content assignment right below the cell allocation like so:

```
// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.accessoryType = [targetRow.children count] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: targetRow.title];
}
```

Since the dequeued cell was found, the content wouldn't get updated.

I changed it to this and all works great now...

```
// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.accessoryType = [targetRow.children count] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: targetRow.title];
```

Comment: I think that's a common mistake when you first start dealing with UITableViews. I know I've done the same thing.

Comment: hi, can you tell me what is the meaning of this line "cell.accessoryType = [targetRow.children count] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
" ? this question mark on the syntax is strange to me... how do I learn to use this ?

Comment: I've always referred to it as an "inline if" statement, not sure if that is the technical term or just geek slang. Basically, it is the same as tapping out: if ([targetRow.children count]) { cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosure; } else { cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; } - Another good tool for lazy programmers :) Also much cleaner to read.